# How can i put Dot Indicator above Carousel slider in flutter,i tried with stack to position it above the carousel image but its not working

Tags: flutter, stack, indicator, carousel-slider

```
Stack(children: [
          CarouselSlider.builder(
              carouselController: controller,
              itemCount: images.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
                final image = images[index];
                return BuildImage(image, index);
              },
              options: CarouselOptions(
                viewportFraction: 1,
                height: 200,
                initialPage: 0,
                reverse: false,
                autoPlay: true,
              )),
          Container(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, child: buildIndicator()),
        ],),
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try `Positioned` like this:

```
Stack(
            children: [
              CarouselSlider.builder(
                        carouselController: controller,
                        itemCount: images.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
                          final image = images[index];
                          return BuildImage(image, index);
                        },
                        options: CarouselOptions(
                          viewportFraction: 1,
                          height: 200,
                          initialPage: 0,
                          reverse: false,
                          autoPlay: true,
                        )),
              Positioned(
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 10,
                child: buildIndicator(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Give alignment to stack widget...

```
Stack(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
      children: [...]
      )
```